# How to get intra day data using blp.bdh function in python Bloomberg

Tags: python, stock, trading, algorithmic-trading, bloomberg

blp.bdib('NIFTY Index',dt = "2023-02-11", enddate='Today',timezone='Calcutta',interval =14)

I want timing start from 9:15AM and its showing 9:16

Tried many thing like ...used all documentation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: blp.bdib('NIFTY Index',dt = "2023-02-11", enddate='Today',timezone='Calcutta',interval =14) By writing this function i'm getting following output.

 NIFTY Index                                          
                                                  open           
2023-03-31 09:16:00+05:30    17235.40 
2023-03-31 09:30:00+05:30    17271.70 
2023-03-31 09:44:00+05:30    17283.20  
2023-03-31 09:58:00+05:30    17271.75  

Here Time starts from 09:16:00 but actually market starts from 09:15:00AM

how to get timing from 09:15:00AM ??

Comment: what `imports` are you using?

Comment: import blpapi
from xbbg import blp

dummy0 = blp.bdib('NIFTY Index',dt = "2023-02-11",enddate='Today',timezone='Calcutta',interval =14)

print(dummy0)

here i'm getting intra day data starts from 9:16 AM but actually Market open at 9:15AM

tried with bdh also.

blp.bdh(tickers='SPX Index', flds=["open",'high', 'low', 'last_price'],start_date='2018-10-10', end_date='2018-10-20')

here i'm not getting intra day data...tried with bdh also

Comment: If you don't want to modify the `xbbg` source code (in site_packages) to remove the somewhat arbitrary +1 minute from open (`s_time = shift_time(ss[0], int(after_open) + 1)` on line 132 of `intervals.py`), then edit the `xbbg\markets\exch.yml` and change the entry for `IndexFuturesIndia` to `[914, 1530]`. There was talk of a merge request to remove the (somewhat random) 1 minute but I don't think it ever happened. Also, `bdib` only returns bars for a single day, so `enddate` is ignored, as is `timezone`. The TZ is picked up from the `exch.yml` file.

Comment: dummy0 = blp.bdib('NIFTY Index',dt = "2023-04-05 T09:15:00", enddate='Today',timezone='Calcutta',interval =14,session ="allday")

print(dummy0)
dummy0
Out[246]: 
                          NIFTY Index            
          ...                      
                                open      high       low  ... volume num_trds value

2023-04-05 09:16:00+05:30    17421.90  17466.30  17421.90  ...      0      840   0.0
2023-04-05 09:30:00+05:30    17464.80  17473.15  17454.35  ...      0      840   0.0
2023-04-05 09:44:00+05:30    17460.55  17475.25  17457.35  ...      0      294   0.0

Comment: @DS_London Sir,

can you show me some example or code??
i did not get this point.

df = blp.bdtick('Nifty Index',datetime(2023,04,05),types=['BID','ASK'],time_range=('08:00','17:00'),ref='CME')
print(df)

still not getting output??

sir ,
if possible can you please show me some idea or example.
s_time = shift_time(ss[0], int(after_open) + 1)  i tried this thing also but still  not getting output.


Thank you sir for support !!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug/feature (take your pick) in the interval processing in the `xbbg` `bdib()` function. The package *explicitly* adds 1 minute to the opening time of the exchange session. This has been raised as an issue, but not fixed as yet (as far as I know).

As background: the underlying Bloomberg API knows nothing about timezones or exchange session hours. Instead it only deals in UTC times. What `xbbg` does is take the given ticker (eg `NIFTY Index`), and attempt to work out what timezone and session hours to use. `xbbg` has a set of *yml* files with exchange information for a lot of tickers / asset classes.

For `NIFTY Index`, the corresponding `xbbg` exchange name is `IndexFuturesIndia` which has a timezone set as `Asia/Calcutta` and the `allday` session as 09:15 to 15:30. Unfortunately, the `bdib` function changes this to 09:16 to 15:30.

**One workaround** (other than to modify the `xbbg` source code or configuration yml files on your machine: *see comments above*) is to amend the session opening time to be one minute earlier. The `bdib` function takes a number of undocumented optional parameters (eg *ref*, *interval*, *config*) which can be used to override the default processing:

```
from xbbg import blp
import datetime

def earlierStartConfig(tkr,dtSession,minsEarlier=1):
    from xbbg import const
    import pandas as pd

    #Get the exchange configuration for this ticker
    exch_config = const.exch_info(tkr)
    session = exch_config['allday']
    hours,mins= ( int(s) for s in session[0].split(':') )
    #Bring the session start time forward by one minute
    session[0] = (dtSession + datetime.timedelta(hours=hours,minutes=mins-minsEarlier)).strftime('%H:%M')
    #Genearate a new exchange config with the new start time
    return pd.DataFrame([{'tz':exch_config.tz,'allday':session}],index=[exch_config.name])

ticker = 'NIFTY Index'
dt = datetime.datetime(2023,4,3)

df = blp.bdib(ticker,dt=dt,session='allday',interval=5,config=earlierStartConfig(ticker,dt))

print(df)
```

with the result:

```
                          NIFTY Index                      ...                      
                                 open      high       low  ... volume num_trds value
2023-04-03 09:15:00+05:30    174xx.xx  174xx.xx  173xx.xx  ...      0      301   0.0
2023-04-03 09:20:00+05:30    173xx.xx  173xx.xx  173xx.xx  ...      0      300   0.0
2023-04-03 09:25:00+05:30    173xx.xx  173xx.xx  173xx.xx  ...      0      300   0.0
2023-04-03 09:30:00+05:30    173xx.xx  173xx.xx  173xx.xx  ...      0      300   0.0
2023-04-03 09:35:00+05:30    173xx.xx  173xx.xx  173xx.xx  ...      0      300   0.0
...                               ...       ...       ...  ...    ...      ...   ...
2023-04-03 15:05:00+05:30    173xx.xx  173xx.xx  173xx.xx  ...      0      300   0.0
2023-04-03 15:10:00+05:30    173xx.xx  174xx.xx  173xx.xx  ...      0      300   0.0
2023-04-03 15:15:00+05:30    174xx.xx  174xx.xx  173xx.xx  ...      0      300   0.0
2023-04-03 15:20:00+05:30    174xx.xx  174xx.xx  173xx.xx  ...      0      300   0.0
2023-04-03 15:25:00+05:30    17398.85  17404.00  17395.00  ...      0      300   0.0

[75 rows x 7 columns]
```

**NB** `bdib` only accepts a single session date (even though the underlying Bloomberg API can use multiple days).

**Alternative solution** Write your own `bdib` function leveraging off `xbbg`'s infrastructure:

```
from datetime import datetime,time

#An intraday bar function which accepts multiple days
def bdibMultiDay(ticker,start_date,end_date,typ,tz,interval=1,session_open=None, session_close=None):
    from xbbg.core import conn,process
    from pandas import DataFrame
    import pytz

    #If no explicit session times given, impute from input datetimes
    if(session_open is None): session_open = start_date.time()
    if(session_close is None): session_close = end_date.time()

    time_fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
    local = pytz.timezone(tz)

    req = process.create_request(service='//blp/refdata',request='IntradayBarRequest')

    req.set('security',ticker)
    req.set('eventType',typ)
    req.set('interval',interval)
    req.set('startDateTime',start_date.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime(time_fmt))
    req.set('endDateTime',end_date.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime(time_fmt))

    conn.send_request(request=req)

    data = ( DataFrame(process.rec_events(func=process.process_bar))
            .set_index('time')
            .rename_axis(index=None)
            .rename(columns={'numEvents': 'num_trds'})
            .tz_localize('UTC')
            .tz_convert(tz) )

    def isInSession(dt) -> bool:
        t = dt.time()
        return (t >= session_open) and (t <= session_close)

    return data.loc[map(isInSession,data.index)]


ticker  = 'NIFTY Index'
start_date = datetime(2023,4,3,9,15)
end_date = datetime(2023,4,6,15,30)
typ = 'TRADE'
tz='Asia/Kolkata'
interval=15

df = bdibMultiDay(ticker,start_date,end_date,typ,tz,interval)
print(df)
```

The main difference is that you have to provide your own time-zone information, rather than use the `xbbg` exchange look-up.

Comment: Thank you for this help.
but As you said,
There is a bug in the xbbg bdib() function.
Can we do the same thing with the help of bdh() or bdtick() function like in intra-day....starts from 9:15AM  ??

df = blp.bdh(tickers='NIFTY Index', flds=['open','high', 'low', 'last_price'],start_date='2023-04-05')

Comment: @TaralMehta I don't get your point. What data do you want? If you want intra-day bar data (OHLC for an interval) use `bdib` if you want intra-day tick data (ie whenever there is a trade or price change) use `bdtick`. If you want end-of-day historical data use `bdh`. Each function returns a different type of data: they are not interchangeable. On Excel, the `=BDH()` function handles both end-of-day and tick data, but with `xbbg` the functions are separate (as they are in the underlying Bloomberg API).

Comment: Actually I want last 1 week  intra day data with some interval.    Where we can change ticker name  if required...in Excel I am getting proper values from bdh easily.  Can we do same thing here??

Comment: @TaralMehta What is the exact Excel formula you are using?

Comment: Ok I got your point... thank you!!!